# From a parent folder, how do I get git to go to specific folders that all have the same suffix using a loop?

Tags: git, cmd, git-bash, git-status

I have a parent folder named 'gitt'   Inside this, I have four subfolders 'gitt1' 'gitt2' 'gitt3' 'gitt4'

Each of these four subfolders have a few folders, including a git repository folder which has the same name as the subfolder +1.0

E.g gitt1 has few folders, including its' repository : gitt11.0

gitt2 has few folders, including its' repository : gitt21.0  etc

From the parent folder gitt, I want a loop command that goes to each of the subfolders, finds the folder with the same name as the subfolder but ending in '1.0' then navigates into it, checks its' `git status` and goes back two levels up.

I have found this `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /ad /b') do cd %a & git status & cd..`
but it only does `git status` on the subfolders and does not go into the folders ending with 1.0

I do not want to make the parent folder(gitt) a repository.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Any of them would do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `FOR /?` to see the modifiers that can be applied to a path. This assumes that `git` can do a status on the directory path specified as a command line parameter. If not, CD may be needed.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN ('DIR /AD /B "C:\src\t\gitt\gitt*"') DO @(ECHO git status "%~dpnxA\%~nxA1.0")
```

As always, double the PERCENT SIGN characters in a .bat file script.

Comment: Thanks. This prints the path of the folders.  How can I get it to do ```git status``` instead?

Comment: Please remove the `ECHO` before the git command if the paths appear correct.